# Convert a spatial point to raster in R

Tags: r, raster

How to convert a single spatial point to a raster object.
I want to create a raster of 0.1 resolution within the domain `xmin = 150 xmx=180,ymin=25,ymax=35` and put the values of a datapoint `dt` point in the raster.

Here is the data and code.

```
dt<-data.frame(lon=71.85,lat =31.12,val=3)
dt
ras_dom<-raster(xmn=150, xmx=180, ymn=25, ymx=35,
                          crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ",
                          resolution=c(0.1,0.1), vals=NA)
ras_dom
```

I want to put the value (or values) from `dt` in the `ras_dom` so that I have a raster with values for given grids and `NA` for others.

Comment: I noticed the longitude and latitude of `dt` have a higher resolution than the raster. On which point in the raster should the point in `dt` be placed? The raster point corresponding to (<lon>, <lat>) (71.8, 31.1), (71.9, 31.1), (71.9, 31.2) or (71.8, 31.2)?

Comment: The nearsest one would be preferred i.e., (<lon>, <lat>) (71.8, 31.1)

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(raster)

coordinates(dt) <- ~ lon + lat # Convert data frame to spatial object
result <- rasterize(dt, ras_dom, "val", update = TRUE) # put point in raster
result # The resulting raster with the point added
```

Because `dt` in the example is outside the raster, `result` does not contain it.